# How could I have MySQL sum() and group by clause within my elasticsearch query?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, get, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying perform an `elasticsearch` query as a `GET` request in order pull data from the index which I created. The data which is in the index is, a table from `MySQL` DB, configured though `logstash`.

Here is my request without the IN clause:

[http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search?q=api:"location"+AND+transactionoperationstatus:"charged"+AND+operatorid='DIALOG'+AND+userid:test+AND+time:"2015-05-27"](http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search?q=api:%22location%22%20AND%20transactionoperationstatus:%22charged%22%20AND%20operatorid='DIALOG'%20AND%20userid:test%20AND%20time:%222015-05-27%22)

In the above, I should be able to append `sum(chargeAmount+0)` & `group by` . I tried giving it a search on the web, but couldn't find any solutions.

Any help could be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you put after the `q=...` in your query uses the same syntax as a [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), so you can rewrite your query to leverage `query_string` and use aggregations to compute the desired sum:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search -d '{
   "query": {
       "query_string": {
           "query": "api:\"location\" AND transactionoperationstatus:\"charged\" AND operatorid:\"DIALOG\" AND userid:test AND time:\"2015-05-27\" AND responseCode:(401 403)"
       }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "total": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "chargeAmount"
          },
          "aggs":{
             "total": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "chargeAmount"
                }
             }
          }
      }
   }
}'
```

In Postman, it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: but then how am I gonna post this `curl` request from postman or something? I tried importing this curl using `postman` but then it says `invalid format`.

Comment: "aggs": {
      "total": {
          "sum": {
              "field": "chargeAmount"
          }
      }
   }
what the above does it to get the sum of `chargeAmount` from the above curl request? The problem is, the field (chargeAmount) in my db is a `varchar` and I guess `sum` here expects a number value. isn't it ?

Comment: I'll look into the `string` value issue, how to give a string field there in the `sum`. How can i go with the `group by`?

Comment: That needs to be a numeric value, indeed. Another option is to use Groovy scripting, but that will be less performant depending on the number of documents you have.

Comment: yes i'll look into that. How about the `group by` thing ? I mean along with the `sum`?

Comment: Ah sorry, you want to group by which field?

Comment: for the `chargeAmount` itslef.